# Encode decode problem while writing to excell worksheet in django view

Tags: python, django, character-encoding, django-views, django-excel

I get below unicodedecodeerror while trying to write to excell worksheet.

> Exception Type:   UnicodeDecodeError
>   Exception Value:
>   'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 7: ordinal not in range(128) The string that could not be encoded/decoded was: i>����R<

My view lines :

```
def file_write(input):
    handle1=open('/tmp/filelog.txt','a')
    handle1.write(str(input))
    handle1.close()

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('report.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

teachertitle = "ÖĞR"
file_write(teachertitle)        
worksheet.write("A4", teachertitle, titlescell)
workbook.close()
```

The strange thing is. File_write function is working well and it writes "ÖĞR" to a local text file. But when i try to write "ÖĞR" to excell workseeht it throws error.

I also tried worksheet.write("A4", teachertitle.encode('utf-8'), titlescell) but still problem continue.

I also have # -*- coding: utf-8 -*- at the beginning of views.py

Comment: Are you using python3 or python2?  Also, can you please post the full trace to your exception?

Comment: The source file encoding should actually be specified with: `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` (note the asterisks).

Comment: right the original code is with *

Answer (score 0):

The problem is most likely with your `file_write` function, where you need to set the encoding of the file to be able to handle `utf-8`.  In python3, you can do that using:

```
def file_write(input):
    handle1=open('/tmp/filelog.txt','a', encoding='utf-8')
    handle1.write(str(input))
    handle1.close()
```

Comment: file_write() is working well. Problem is with excell workbook

Answer (score 0):

At last,

Solution is :

> worksheet.write("A4", teachertitle.decode('utf-8'), titlescell)

Decoding solved it. As i understand excell workbook needs the string to be decoded before writing to excell sheet.